# Мультиаплоад с добавлением в базу.

Tags: php, mysql

Существует некий модуль, допустим новости, две связанные таблицы, `news(id,text)` и `files(id,news_id,src)`, при создании новости каждый пользователь может загрузить фотографии. Фотографии грузятся мультиаплоадом, аяксом с превьюшками. картинки загружаются до фактического создания новости, соответвенно `news_id` неизвестен. Как всё это грамотно организовать? Включая, хранение временных файлов, очистку, добавление. Крон и тригеры не использовать.

Comment: Для мультизагрузки можно попробовать http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: @sambady у меня свои инструменты, но спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Черновик**

идея навеяна gmail'ом так как картинки заливать могут, только зарегистрированные пользователи, соответвено при новой загрузке файла, автоматически создаем черновик, если новость публикуются автоматически чистим черновик и преобразуем его в новость, иначе добавляем в черновики, которые пользователь по своему усмотрению, может редактировать либо удалять. таким образом мы расширяем функционал, и избавляемся от крона, заказчик прыгает от счастья, мы наслаждаемся красивым решением.

Comment: Т.е. при создании новости (печатании текста) время от времени сохранять ее в черновики?

Comment: @Dobby007 да именно так, либо при загрузке фотографии.

Comment: хорошая идея...

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, загружать и после ответа аякс создавать в форме добавления

```
<input type="hidden" name="files[]" value="<?=$new_file_rel_path?>" />
```

И собственно все) Единственное, надо периодически чистить неиспользованные файлы (или не чистить, если "фрагментация").

Comment: вот в чистке как раз таки и проблема, как её по хитрому организовать, а что по поводу "фрагментации", не понял.

Comment: Да история была, вконтакт отказался удаленные фотки удалять физически, потому что это "повышает фрагментацию".

Ну вообще это как раз кроном и делается. 

Можно:

 - сделать кнопку "удалить файл" еще при создании новости, чтобы его тут же удаляло
 - писать юзеру (в базу) загруженные фотки, при создании новости удалять то, что запилено в новость. А потом при логине/отсутствии более N часов удалять все что в этом списке (статья не создана).
 - крон (ежедневный проход по всем файлам за последние сутки с проверкой их в списке файлов в БД)

Comment: Еще такой хитрый изврат - в форме создания сделать стучалку раз в 30 сек, и если ее, допустим, 2 мин не слышно - удалить файлы. Но такой вариант чреват тем, что обрыв инета превратит статью в кашу. От этого тоже можно спастись, если и на клиенте закрывать форму добавления через те же 2 мин после последнего ответа стучалки. Но, если честно, это похоже на тот случай, когда решение проблемы плодит 2 новых.

Comment: @Sh4dow еще один хитрый изврат, но пока еще не узнавал насколько это реально, если бы была возможность отправлять файлы дважды, первый при аплоаде для превьюшки, а второй раз с телом новости на добавление.

Comment: @FLK, а если файлов штук 5 и все по 15 мегабайт? Два раза их отправлять пользователю не в кайф как-то будет. Да и у вас на сервере место на диске не бесконечное. Плюс еще @Sh4dow писал про фрагментацию...

Comment: @Dobby007 тоже уже подумал, что дваждый файлы загружать это издевательство над юзерами ) чтобы возвращать превьюшки не обязательно сохранять файлы на диске. но сама идея лишена элегантности, придется видимо по старинке кроном чистить.

Answer (score 0):

Может создать таблицу temporary_files (пускай даже MEMORY), и писать в нее файлы с временным id новости, который генерируется по нажатию кнопки "Создать новость" по принципу:

```
SELECT MAX(news_id) FROM temporary_files
```

Потом, когда заполнит все поля и нажмет Отправить делаете:

```
INSERT INTO files SELECT id, $last_insert_news_id, src FROM temporary_files WHERE news_id = $id
DELETE FROM temporary_files WHERE news_id = $id
```

Если нужно чистить, то время от времени можно проходиться по таблице и удалять эти временные файлы по времени загрузки (если больше двух часов, то им там, согласитесь, делать нечего), например. Т.е. если в таблице будет поле date, то:

```
SELECT id, src FROM temp_files WHERE date > NOW() + INTERVAL 2 HOUR; - чтобы удалить файлы и
DELETE FROM temp_files WHERE id IN(implode($array))
```

Может конечно кривовато, но это первое, что пришло в голову.

**UPD:**

Извиняюсь, но запрос `SELECT MAX(news_id) FROM temporary_files` не прокатит, поскольку может быть ситуация, когда один пользователь, создающий новость, еще не загрузил ни одного файла, а другой, нажавший кнопку чуть позже, уже загрузил, тогда первый, увидит в своем списке чужие файлы. Так что, чтобы этого избежать нужно будет брать последний сгенерированный `news_id` с какого-нибудь другого источника. Вообще говоря, этот `news_id` лучше хранить в memcache, например, или в файле, в крайнем случае. Да уж... Наверное можно как-то по-другому сделать, что-то сильно как-то "наворочено" получилось))

**UPD2:**

Вы же, когда загрузите файл (после добавления файла в `temp_files`) будете знать его id. Все равно кнопку "Удалить файл" нужно будет сделать. Тогда можно просто после отправки файлов, эти id файлов вставлять в постоянную таблицу files. Тогда колонка `news_id` в temp_files не нужна (обойдемся колонками id, src и date). Т.е. должно быть что-то вроде:

```
INSERT INTO files (SELECT id, $last_insert_news_id, src FROM temporary_files WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4))
```

Comment: откровенно говоря, не вижу особого смысла в дополнительной таблице, можно просто указывать user_id к примеру 0 и потом точно так же периодически удалять неиспользованные файлы по времени.